# How to send files from frontend (Next.js) to backend (express)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using useFormState hook to send the formdata to express backend and in is logging the 'image' file on the frontend . But in the express backend , i unable to get any field like 'image' in the req body .

```
const[state,formAction] =useFormState(actions,{success:false,status:null})
```

This the my form component:

```
 <form ref={formRef}encType='multipart/form-data'  action={formAction} >
    <input
    name="title"
    type='text'
      className="w-full p-2 border rounded mb-4"
      rows="4"
      placeholder="Title" 
    ></input>
   {renderErrors('title')}
    <textarea
    type='text'
    name="description"
      className="w-full p-2 border rounded mb-4"
      rows="4"
      placeholder="Whats on your mind"
      // value={postContent}
      // onChange={(e) => setPostContent(e.target.value)}
    ></textarea>
     {renderErrors('description')}
    
    <div className="mb-4">
      <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="fileInput">
        Upload a file:
      </label>
      <input
        type="file"
        id="fileInput"
        name='image'
        className="w-full border rounded py-2 px-3"
        // onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])}
      />
    </div>
    <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded hover:bg-blue-600"
      >
        Post
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And this is my action :

```
 "use server"
import axios from "axios";
export  async function actions(prevstate,formdata) {
    try {
        const { title, description,image } = Object.fromEntries(formdata);
        console.log(image);
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/add-post', { title, description,image, author: "gaurav" });
        return {...prevstate, success: true ,status:Object.keys(response.data)[0] };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response.data);
        return { ...prevstate,success: false, status: error.response.data };
    }
   

}
```

To be noted that i am able to log the image in the action , but the req.file in the express backend returns undefined . I am handling the image upload using muter package. **Also when I am using postman , it works fine (File gets stored in MongoDb). Is there any issue with how am am using the useFormState hook?**

I know storing files in mongodb is not recommended , but i am just learning and trying to understand the whole thing (self learning).

For the reference of how i am using the multer package, below the the code for it:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
const postController = require('../controller/postController')
router.post('/api/add-post', upload.single('image'), postController.addPost)
module.exports = router
```

And below the the controller:

```
const { User, Post } = require('../models');

exports.addPost = async (req, res) => {
    try {            // return res.status(400).json({ haha: error });

        const { title, description, author } = req.body;
        const post = new Post({ title, description, author });
        console.log("file",req.file);
        post.image.data = req.file.buffer;
        savedPost = await post.save();
        return res.status(200).json({ "Post added": savedPost });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        if (error.name === 'ValidationError') {
            // Mongoose validation error
            const validationErrors = Object.entries(error.errors).map(([name, errorObject]) => ({
                [name]: errorObject.message,
            }));            
            
            return res.status(400).json({  errors: validationErrors });

        }
        else{
            return res.status(500).json({  error: "Internal Server Error" });
        }
    }
};
```